# "Ваш голос за удаление учтён" при голосовании за восстановление

Tags: дефект, локализация, голосование

При голосовании за восстановление выводится сообщение об удалении.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В траде всё норм https://ru.traducir.win/filters?translationRegex=%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%88%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%20

Comment: Удалить нельзя восстановить.

Comment: [Всё украдено до нас.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295184/339911)

Comment: @älёxölüt так проблема всё-таки на всех сайтах?

Comment: Все не проверял ;) но на [MSE сейчас работает правильно](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izWnA.png). Может затронут только руСО, а может и другие локализованные. Можно попробовать передернуть перевод: например, немного изменить, применить и проверить. Если что, откатить назад и форсировать фикс.

Comment: @älёxölüt интересно. Но эт ж явно не косяк перевода.

Comment: Надо бы запостить обновление на MSE с моей картинкой. Есть возможность? А то я на телефоне весь день.

Comment: Я там вчера вообще пост создавал https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321006/260198 (:

Comment: @älёxölüt вечером смогу только, сейчас на работе.

Comment: Восстановлен...

Comment: Обновление дописал в общем. Можно дальше работать ;)